# Ubuntu freezes in recursion g++

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++

Im using `Ubuntu 14.04` and `gcc version 4.8.2`. Sometimes when I run some `C++` code which has some bugs, for example `Runtime Error`, it goes to a deep `recursion` (I suppose...) and all my computer freezes. I can do nothing. `Ctrl+C, Ctr+Alt+F1..F7, Mouse`, any buttons doesnt work. Even my power button. So I have to hold it to power off my computer. This Ubuntu or gcc bug is pissing me off! Does anybody know how to fix it?

My compilation line: `g++ -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra`

g++ version: `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2`

Ubuntu version: `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`

I have absolutely same behavior on both of my computers. (And my fried too. I have 2 `ASUS` comps and my fried has `DELL`)

Comment: Runtime Error leads to unpredictable behavior, so it seems to me that nothing can be done.

Comment: I hadnt got any problems like this one when I used Windows. So Im pretty sure that its just some bug or something like that. Do you always power off your computer when have some RE bug in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having sometimes the same issue. It is not caused by recursion itself but by Linux going out of memory. Linux lets programs to allocate as much space as they need until there is absolutely no memory left. Because of this, your machine becomes unable to handle primitive operations.

Windows behaves in slightly another way. It leaves some free space for it's needs. Your code would get "Out of memory" error, and the system would work very slow for a little bit, but not totally freeze.

The same idea is used by `fork-bomb` attack, which takes all the memory in the system so quick that even `killall` is unable to run.

If your program takes so much memory uncontroled, it will soon die and then Linux would run OK. The only way that helped me in making it faster currently is to send `Ctrl-C` to the terminal where your code is launched from or trying to run `killall`.

Comment: I forgot to tell that out of memory is produced by very deep recursion, where every step allocates stack memory. Futher more, on Windows you can limit stack memory, but you can't on Linux.

Comment: And whould you do if `Ctrl-C` doesnt work?

Comment: @Dima Wait with hope. Or you always have the power button)

Comment: I had the same issue. no button combination can kill it. finally when when i was going to press power button, I saw "Command Terminated" and then system was out of freeze. As @Lapshin Dmitry said, power button will always be there at ur service.